# Mapping items from one class to another if Items are equivalent

Tags: c#, class, oop, mapping

Say I have one `class` that looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public int Number {get; set;}
}
```

And another that looks like this:

```
public class Dog
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public int Number {get; set;}
}
```

They are two different classes, but they happen to have the exact same elements (a string called `Name` and an int called `Number`)

Is there an easy way in C# to, say, if I had an instance of `Person` to then create an instance of `Dog` with the same `Name` and `Number`?

For example if I had:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Name = "George";
person.Number = 1;
```

I know I can't simply go:

```
Dog dog = person;
```

Because they are two different types. But is there a way in C# to check "oh, if they have the same element, set the same elements of `Dog` to equal that of `Person`.
But I feel there has to be an easier way than doing something like:

```
dog.Name = person.Name;
dog.Number = person.Number;
```

Especially if the class has a LOT of elements. Also if anyone is wondering, these two different classes are in two different pieces of the API, so I can't simply make them related either.

Comment: You can have a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: If `Dog` and `Person` are not sub-classes of the same base class then imo it does not follow that you can simply clone one and make it the other.  However, you could use reflection to achieve this by enumerating the properties of both object instances and invoking the `get` and `set` accessors as appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/):

```
public Dog UsingAMR(Person prs)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Person, Dog>();
    });
    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    return mapper.Map<Person, Dog>(prs);
}
```

Then you can easily:

```
Person ps = new Person {Name = "John", Number = 25};
Dog dog = UsingAMR(ps);
```

Just don't forget to **install `AutoMapper` first** from the package manager console as mentioned in the reference:

1. From *Tools* menu click on *NuGet Package Manager* ==> *Package Manager Console*
2. Then type the following command:

   ```
   PM> Install-Package AutoMapper
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Install `AutoMapper` package in your project.

As a best practice (for web applications) you can create new class (should derives from `Profile`) in your `App_Start` folder, that will contain all your mappings for your project.

```
namespace MyApp.App_Start
{
    public class MyAppMapping : Profile
    {
        public MyAppMapping()
        {

            CreateMap<Person, Dog>();

            //You can also create a reverse mapping
            CreateMap<Dog, Person>();

            /*You can also map claculated value for your destination. 
            Example: you want to append "d-" before the value that will be
            mapped to Name property of the dog*/

            CreateMap<Person, Dog>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Days, 
             conf => conf.ResolveUsing(AppendDogName)); 
        }

        private static object AppendDogName(Person person)
        {
            return "d-" + person.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Then Initialize your mapping inside the `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<MyAppMapping>());
}
```

You can now use the mappings that you have created

```
var dog = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Person, Dog>(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

An object oriented approach.

```
public class Mammal
{
    public Mammal(Mammal toCopy)
    {
        Name = toCopy.Name;
        Number = toCopy.Number;
    }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;}
}
public class Person: Mammal
{
    public Person(Mammal toCopy) {} /* will default to base constructor */
}

public class Dog: Mammal
{
    public Dog(Mammal toCopy) {} /* will default to base constructor */
}
```

This will allow the following:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Name = "George";
person.Number = 1;
Dog dog = new Dog(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't work with big generic list, you can do it using LinQ.

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
// populate data [...]
var dogs = persons.Select(p=>new Dog{Name=p.Name,Number=p.Number}).ToList();
```

It's easy to remember, and you can filter data previously.