# Copy list from one class to list in another class

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to copy a list from one class to another list in a different class. There is actually 4 objects being used.

In my view I am displaying a list of items with -

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PointList)
{
     //my items displayed
}
```

I have the list that a need `Model.PointList`

```
public partial class OrificeCert
{
 public List<OrificeCertPoint> PointList { get; set; }

}
```

With referenced `OrificeCertPoint` being:

```
public partial class OrificeCertPoint
{
    public string Total { get; set; }
    public string Raw { get; set; }
    public string Flow { get; set; }
    public string Diff { get; set; }
    public string Background { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the other new list

```
public partial class Temp_OrificeCert
{
    public List<Temp_OrificeCertPoints> TempPointList { get; set; }
}
```

With referenced `Temp_OrificeCertPoint` being:

```
public partial class Temp_OrificeCertPoint
{
    public string Total { get; set; }
    public string Raw { get; set; }
    public string Flow { get; set; }
    public string Diff { get; set; }
    public string Background { get; set; }
}
```

The code in my controller is:

```
tempCert.TempPointList = db.Temp_OrificeCertPoints
                .Where(x => x.OrificeCertID == 1).ToList();
//one attempt
List<OrificeCertPoint> newList =   CopyTo.tempCert.TempPointList;
//another attempt
model.PointList = tempCert.TempPointList;
```

I have tried several others but I keep getting a message stating I cannot `convert`Temp_OrificeCertPoint`to`OrificeCertPoint

I need the `Model.PointList` to contain the list of `tempCert.TempPointList`

Comment: They are not the same types. One is `List<OrificeCertPoint>` the other `List<Temp_OrificeCertPoints>`... You could use an interface but I fail to see why you would want two of exactly the same models in the first place. Or a base/abstract class..

Comment: I think this answer could be helpful, for what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/39515990/2946329

Comment: I agree with S.Akbari, you would profit from using AutoMapper for such type conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different classes, they are not convertible to each other. You have to do that yourself:

```
public partial class OrificeCertPoint
{
    public string Total { get; set; }
    public string Raw { get; set; }
    public string Flow { get; set; }
    public string Diff { get; set; }
    public string Background { get; set; }

    public static OrificeCertPoint CreateFrom(Temp_OrificeCertPoint copyPoint)
    {
        return new OrificeCertPoint
        {
            Total = copyPoint.Total,
            Raw = copyPoint.Raw ,
            Flow = copyPoint.Flow,
            Diff = copyPoint.Diff,
            Background = copyPoint.Background  
        };
    }
}
```

Now you can use:

```
model.PointList = tempCert.TempPointList.ConvertAll(OrificeCertPoint.CreateFrom);
```