# Accidental Object Reference

Tags: c#, oop, methods, reference

I was working on a project of mine when something didn't work as I expected, and now I am reevaluating my entire being. Take the following class and method:

```cs
public class Test{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public Test ReturnExample(Test test)
{
     Test example = test;
     example.Name = "abc";
     return example;
}
```

Now, if I have a `FirstValue` and a `SecondValue`:

```cs
Test FirstValue = new Test {Name = "First", Value = 8 };
Test SecondValue = new Test {Name = "Second", Value = 12 };
```

All seems pretty generic and straightforward so far but what surprised me was when you do:

```cs
SecondValue = ReturnExample(FirstValue);
```

What I expected the values to be after was:

```
    FirstValue:
       Name = "First"
       Value = 8
    SecondValue:
       Name = "abc"
       Value = 8
```

However, what I got was:

```
    FirstValue:
       Name = "abc"
       Value = 8
    SecondValue:
       Name = "abc"
       Value = 8
```

So, what's going on here and what can I change to get what I want?

Comment: Start reading about the reference values.

Comment: Side note: normally inlining all the code involved into single method would be an explanation that you should be able  to do yourself... But since you have a problem with how parameters are passed I don't think you could do that... Hopefully @SalahAkbari comment+answer and canonical duplicate should clarify things.

Comment: What are you talking about? You commented after I had accepted the answer, so I'm unclear with that you are trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm):

> Reference Types are used by a reference which holds a reference
> (address) to the object but not the object itself. Because reference
> types represent the address of the variable rather than the data
> itself, assigning a reference variable to another doesn't copy the
> data. Instead it creates a second copy of the reference, which refers
> to the same location of the heap as the original value. Reference Type
> variables are stored in a different area of memory called the heap.
> This means that when a reference type variable is no longer used, it
> can be marked for garbage collection.

With that being said, if you want your code works as expected you need to do a deep copy instead:

```
public Test ReturnExample(Test test)
{
    Test example = new Test();
    example.Name = "abc";
    example.Value = test.Value;
    return example;
}
```

Comment: For more complex types, like the one in my program, doing it value by value would be very clunky, are there ways to deep copy more complex types simply?

Comment: @Bubinga Sure, you can use a tool like AutoMapper for this purpose. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39515990/2946329