# C# Deep Clone of a List Data

Tags: c#

I have properties as below;

```
public class Employer
{
public int IDNumber { get; set; }
public DateTime RegDate { get; set; }
public List<BioData> BioInfo { get; set; }
}
```

BioData.cs

```
 public class BioData
    {
        public int IndexID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public double Salary { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to Deep Clone Employer List including all the fields and properties to the same Employer list.

Comment: I have tried to get a copy and AddRange to the same list, it didn't work.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c

Comment: @SupunSilva Have you tried any of the answers for the duplicate question?

Comment: Tried with all of the answers in the duplicate questions. There is no clear answer for this issue.

Comment: How much data do you have to clone?

Comment: use version specific tags only if your question is about this version specifically or if you want to say that the solution should be compatible to that old version.

Comment: You can use a tool like `AutoMapper` for this purpose. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39515990/2946329

Comment: Did you try to search in SO? There are hundert of questions explaining how to deep clone (with automapper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a method or the IClonable Interface to clone your data.
I prefere my own method with a clear name (shallow or deep clone):

```
public sealed class Employer
{
    public int IDNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegDate { get; set; }
    public List<BioData> BioInfo { get; set; }

    public Employer DeepClone()
    {
        Employer loClone = new Employer()
        {
            IDNumber = this.IDNumber,
            RegDate = this.RegDate
        };
        if (this.BioInfo != null)
            loClone.BioInfo = this.BioInfo.Select(item => item.DeepClone()).ToList();
        return loClone;
    }
}

public sealed class BioData 
{
    public int IndexID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }

    public BioData DeepClone()
    {
        //Can also use here
        //return this.MemberwiseClone() as BioData;
        return new BioData()
        {
            IndexID = this.IndexID,
            Description = String.Copy(this.Description),
            Age = this.Age,
            Salary = this.Salary
        };
    }
}
```

UPDATE
To copy the entries from an existing list in the same list, you can use LINQ.
(`ToList` is necessary):

```
List<Employer> loList = new List<Employer>();
loList.ToList().ForEach(item => loList.Add(item.DeepClone()));
```

Comment: This Code is fine and getting a clone to 1loClone`, I want to add this clone data in the existing list.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to provide a copy-constructor for `BioData`. You should also seal the class, so you don't need to worry about handling copying derived class data:

```
public sealed class BioData
{
    public BioData()
    {
        // Initialise members or not, as you like.
    }

    public BioData(BioData other)
    {
        IndexID     = other.IndexID;
        Description = other.Description;
        Age         = other.Age;
        Salary      = other.Salary;
    }

    public int    IndexID     { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int    Age         { get; set; }
    public double Salary      { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can clone the list like so:

```
var clone = BioInfo.Select(item => new BioData(item)).ToList();
```

Comment: BioData list is in separate file

Comment: @SupunSilva And where in your question do you state anything about data being in a file? How do you expect people to be able to answer a question you haven't asked? Please go and edit your question and add all pertinent information!

Comment: Employer List has a subList named BioData. I want to deep clone Employer List including all the fields and subLists.

Comment: @SupunSilva Can you post the declaration of the class that has a sublist named BioData?

Comment: With the above code, I can't add new items to the BioData. `new BioData(){IndexID=1, Description ="112dfdf", ....}`

Comment: @SupunSilva I've added a default constructor to my sample code. As soon as you add a non-default constructor, the auto-generated one is no longer auto-generated, so you have to manually add one.

Comment: @QuarK What do you mean? The lining up? Resharper does that for me by default...

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, it's strange if it's default lining up for Resharper. Mine doesn't add extra spaces after type and name.